# count of switch case from database

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have some code :

```
switch (sabtReqID)
{
    case 0: //user enter name
          req = new SendMessage(item.Message.Chat.Id, "please enter name")
          { ReplyMarkup = returnMenu };
          await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
          sabtReqID = 1;
          break;

    case 1: //user enter father
          req = new SendMessage(item.Message.Chat.Id, "please enter faather")
          { ReplyMarkup = returnMenu };
          await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
          sabtReqID = 2;
          break;
```

How to write this code to read sabtReqID  from database and then read case counts from database. for example this sample have 2 cases. But other conditions have more than 2 case and have different variables. For example this sample have name and father variables. but other conditions have different vars like age and address and etc. how to create a class and programatically this codes.

Comment: It's very unclear what *specifically* you need help with. Do you know how to read fields from a table in the database? Do you know how to step through a database cursor getting multiple rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version https://dotnetfiddle.net/JO8F8f works like your requirement, I think.
Each class has an Id, equivalent your sabtReqID loaded from database. By comparing this ID, I found a right class with a right method to be executed.

Can you try this :

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         var sabtReqID = 0;

            var myCase = ReflectiveEnumerator.GetEnumerableOfType<Case>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == sabtReqID);
            if (myCase != null)
            {
                myCase.Todo();
            }
        }

        public static class ReflectiveEnumerator
        {
            static ReflectiveEnumerator() { }

            public static IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerableOfType<T>() where T : class
            {
                List<T> objects = new List<T>();
                foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(T)).GetTypes()
                    .Where(myType => myType.IsClass && !myType.IsAbstract && myType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))))
                {
                    objects.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(type));
                }
                return objects;
            }
        }
    }


public abstract class Case
{
    public abstract void Todo();

    public virtual int Id { get; }
}

public class NameCase : Case
{
    public override int Id => 0;
    public override void Todo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NameCase Hello World");
    }
}

public class FatherNameCase : Case
{
    public override int Id => 1;
    public override void Todo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FatherNameCase Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is a nice solution, it does not really fit the problem description. There is no "database" at all in your answer.

Comment: I think you don't look at in detail the question, sabtReqID is charged from DB and it is outside context of the question...

Comment: thanks. how to get id and todo from database table ?

Comment: @amintafteh my answer is about programming the action for each value sabtReqID charged from DB. 
The action of getting the id sabtReqID and the name of method todo, you can arrange yourself in DB and make the request SQL. Right?